# Is it possible to get a value of an enum member at compile time?

Tags: c, gcc, enums, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to get a value of an enum member at compile time?

In fact, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
enum { 
   FOO_FIRST = -1,
   FOO_A,
   FOO_B,
   FOO_C,
   FOO_LAST
};

#if FOO_LAST > 10
//...
#else
//..
#endif
```

I know that the `cpp` don't know about variables, bad syntax, etc; only things that start with a `#`(right)? but members of an enum has fixed-size and cannot be changed just like 10 (constant integer) value and the compiler know its size and values. so, Is there no any possibility to do such comparison (as I did above)? Could I use gcc-extensions?

I don't wish to rewrite all my enumerations by using `#define`s and don't take my time doing some macros change.

Comment: What are you trying to do inside your `#if` blocks?

Comment: can't think of any actual use case where this is useful..

Comment: [enum and #define](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136946/difference-between-enum-and-define-statements)

Comment: One-of is the following: if the last enum member is greater than `7`, I need to put a lot of if() conditions and loops, otherwise just: `if(foo) { exp1; }`

Comment: why? do you need the number of bits it uses, or what? if you don't explain the "why", it's still just a weird requirement and not an actual useful case

Comment: because this value is variable. Don't depends me how long it is. For example, the current value the enumeration has 7-members in the next time that I will compile it, I don't know. If it's possible, just would less time to edit source code. if #enum_member_x > 10 it's possible, some if() will help me a lot. It's the question. I asked it because I want no rewrite back my enum by using defines. But as it's not possible(until I see now), I'II do it. (sorry for my ba english, not a native speaker)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use `if`. Enums can be evaluated at compile time just fine. The compiler will optimize the impossible branches out:

```
if (FOO_LAST > 10) {
    // A
} else {
    // B
}
```

The compiler knows which of the two branches (A and B) cannot be reached, so it can eliminate the `if` completely.

Note however, that you should only use the enumerators directly. For example, in this:

```
int num = FOO_LAST;
if (num > 10) {
    // A
} else {
    // B
}
```

GCC will *keep* the `if` comparison.

Comment: Very nice. I'II try it. Do you have a link with such optimization details? (we are talking on gcc?)

Comment: See this to get an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281471/disable-if0-elimination-in-gcc You don't even have to enable the optimizer to get this behavior. Compile an example program with `-O2 -S` to get the assembly file. You'll see that there's no branching.

Comment: I'm sorry "we are" must be "are we" :)

Comment: I forgot the case where you don't use the enumerators directly. I updated the answer.

Comment: both gcc and clang remove the branch, even with `int num = LAST`.  [See here](https://godbolt.org/g/7ox1Vn)

Answer (score 3):

`#ifdef` is interpreted by the preprocessor and not by the compiler. The pre-processor does not know anything about the `enums`'s values. So this is not a way to go.