# disable all obvious elimination when compiling with gcc (without changing my source code!)

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, compilation, code-elimination

I want to keep all dead code (or anything that is even obviously can be optimized) when compiling with gcc, but even with `-O0`, some dead code are still optimized. How can I keep all code **without changing my source code**? The sample code is as follows, and when compiling with `g++ -S -O0 main.cc`, the `if-statement` will be optimized in assembly code (there will be no `cmpl` and `jmp` code).

```cpp
int main() {
  constexpr int a = 123; // or const int a = 0; I do not want to remove `const` or `constexpr` qualifier.
  if (a) // or just if (123)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

A related question is here: [Disable "if(0)" elimination in gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281471/disable-if0-elimination-in-gcc). But the answers there need you to change your source code (remove const/constexpr qualifier) which I do not want to do.

Could it be that I do not change my source code but only use some compiler flags to achieve this?

Comment: What you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: C and C++ compilers are explicitely allowed to use the *as if* rule: they are free to rearrange the source code the way they want **provided the observables results are the same of what a naive strictly conformant implementation could produce**. And gcc is known to aggressively optimize out dead code or code that would have lead to UB... Maybe you could try a different compiler?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat For now it's just for some simple tests.

Comment: Then the answer is "probably not possible". If you explain what this is for, then we might be able to suggest alternative solutions.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, and I suppose the extent of this as-if rule is determined by `-O` and some other flags, but it seems not possible to achieve `0-extent` effect of this rule. I also check clang and the result is the same.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am just curious with the [`constexpr if-statement`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), because if `const` in a `if-statement` has the same effect of a `constexpr if-statement`, then why do I need to use a `constexpr if-statement` instead of only using `const`? And this is another reason that I want to ensure whether on earth they are all the same (optimized to the same code no matter what flags you provide) for compilers.

Comment: Well I hoped that we could easily find *toy* C++ compilers with no optimisations at all as results of student trainings. But a google search did not show any. Maybe C++ language is way to complex for that...

Comment: @Daniel The difference can only be seen in templates, when the condition of `if constexpr` depends on a template parameter. Then, the branch that's not taken is validated less strictly (compared to regular `if`), allowing you to have things in it (depending on template parameters) that wouldn't compile otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is not possible with GCC** to keep the conditional in this case since it is removed during a very early stage of the compilation.

First of all, here is the compilation steps of GCC:

1. Code parsing (syntax & semantics) producing an AST in GENERIC representation (HL-IR)
2. High-level GIMPLE generation (ML-IR)
3. Low-level GIMPLE generation (ML-IR)
4. Tree SSA optimization (ML-IR)
5. RTL generation (LL-IR)
6. Code optimization
7. Assembly generation

The conditional is already removed after the generation of the (theoretically unoptimized) high-level GIMPLE representation. Thus, before any optimization step. One can check this by using the GCC flag `-fdump-tree-all` and look at the first generated GIMPLE code. Here is the result:

```
;; Function int main() (null)
;; enabled by -tree-original
{
  const int a = 123;

  <<cleanup_point   const int a = 123;>>;
  return <retval> = 1;
  return <retval> = 0;
}
return <retval> = 0;
```

One can note that the resulting code is the same with both `constexpr` and `const`. Actually, `constexpr` is treated as a simple `const` variable in the HL GIMPLE code.

It is hard to know when the conditional is exactly removed in Step 1 as GENERIC is an implementation-dependent internal representation of GCC. It is not very flexible/customizable. AFAIK, it is not even yet possible to generate the AST/GENERIC representation. You can extract it yourself with some GCC plugins, but this is a quite tricky task.